# Convert apache.axis.types.Duration to HH:mm format

Tags: java, apache, date, date-conversion, datetime-conversion

Please refer below main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Duration dur = new Duration();
    dur.setHours(17);
    dur.setMinutes(30);

    SimpleDateFormat simpDate = new SimpleDateFormat("kk:mm");
    System.out.println(simpDate.format(dur.getAsCalendar().getTime()));
}
```

When i run this i got output 05:30 and expected output is 17:30. Even i tried with "HH:mm" format but not getting expected output. it converts to 12 hours format rather than 24 hours format.

Please help.

Comment: Can I double check - those are lower-case 'k' in your SimpleDateFormat?

Comment: yes it is ..... even i tried with "HH".

Answer (score 0):

Why cant you simple use

```
System.out.println(dur.getHours()+":"+dur.getMinutes());
```